Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS)
I am using breeze framework. In my defaultbreezevalidator.ts , I have
if (meta.regEx) {
      validators.push(this.regexValidator({ regex: meta.regEx.expression, name: meta.displayName, messageTemplate: meta.regEx.errorMessage }));
}

private static regexValidator(context: Context) {
    return this.validator(context,
        '%displayName% is not in the correct format',
        'regex_' + context["name"],
        (value, ctxt) => {
            if (!value || value == null) { return true; }

            const patt = new RegExp(context["regex"], 'igm');
            return patt.test(value);
        }
    );
}

Now I a getting Unsanitized user input from browser storage flows into RegExp, where it is used to build a regular expression. This may result in a Regular expression Denial of Service attack (reDOS) at line const patt = new RegExp(context["regex"], 'igm');. How do I resolve this vulnerability as I cannot give set of hardcoded regular expressions as they are dynamic and cannot remove special characters.
I tried removing special characters just to check if i am able to resolve vulnerability.
private static regexValidator(context: Context) {
    return this.validator(context,
        '%displayName% is not in the correct format',
        'regex_' + context["name"],
        (value, ctxt) => {
            if (!value || value == null) { return true; }
            const escapeRegex = (str: string) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
            const safePattern = escapeRegex(context["regex"]);
            const patt = new RegExp(safePattern, 'igm');
            return patt.test(value);
        }
    );
}

This resolved my vulnerability but I cannot remove special characters as they change the purpose of regular expression.
I also tried below code just to check if validating the pattern will remove vulnerability, but it did not work.
private static regexValidator(context: Context) {
  return this.validator(
    context,
    '%displayName% is not in the correct format',
    'regex_' + context["name"],
    (value, ctxt) => {
      if (!value || value == null) { return true; }

      const safePattern = context["regex"];
      if (!isValidPattern(safePattern)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid regex pattern');
      }

      const patt = new RegExp(safePattern, 'igm');
      return patt.test(value);
    }
  );
}

function isValidPattern(pattern: string): boolean {
  if (pattern.length > 100) return false; // Example length check
  return true;
}

I need help in resolving this vulnerability in scan

Unfortunately you can't allow both any regular expression and be safe. Any limitation that would prevent catastrohpic backtracking is going to significantly reduce the expressivity of the regex.

It sounds as if you think this is an issue because the user is able to change the browser storage to manipulate the regex. Where is this .ts file executed? If the regex is also executed in the browser, is it really an issue? They can only "attack" themselves.

Check Can I detect a hanging JS function and abort?
